# Recursive replacement in a text file (regular expressions)

Tags: regex, bash, recursion, sed

I would like to make a recursive replacement of variables into a text file, possibly using regular expressions, and so a very simple bash script.

This is the text file that I have:

```
 ###MS: 12/
 ###MSMS: 13/
 BEGIN IONS
 TITLE= Cmpd 1, +MSn(507.7145), 0.1 min
 PEPMASS=507.71453  5708

 ###MS: 12/
 ###MSMS: 14/
 BEGIN IONS
 TITLE= Cmpd 2, +MSn(637.6461), 0.1 min
 PEPMASS=637.64610  8328
```

The text file is made of a multiple repetitions of the same-structured block (as you can see in the figure): what I would like to achieve is the replacement of the number after `TITLE= Cmpd` with the number after `###MSMS`. This should be done for every block, scrolling the text file, assigning this `Cmpd` value with the `MSMS` one for each block.

I tried with `sed`, using a script that was previously explained here on StackOverflow, but using `Cmpd [0-9]` works only for the second part (the replacement) but not for the selection of the numbers after `MSMS`.

```
while read line
 do
   varA="###MSMS: "[0-9][0-9]
   varB="Cmpd "[0-9]
   line='echo$line|sed -e "s/$varA/$varB/"'
   echo&line >> "outputfile.txt"
done < "inputfile.txt"
```

I really thank you in advance, this will be a perfect occasion to learn more about this stuff.

Comment: Please consider editing your question to include your expected output, giving these inputs. Its also shows that you're not just looking for free coding services, by including your attempt to solve the problem, including your current output and exact error messages. Good luck.

Comment: Sounds like you need to try multiple passes. First use regex to find the MSMS and save the number to a variable, then when you use regex to find the Cmpd number you can replace it with the saved value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the hold buffer. In sed the `h` command copies the current pattern space into the hold buffer, and the `G` command retrieves that and appends it, with a newline, to the pattern space.

The sed script below extracts the MSMS number and stores it in the pattern buffer, then when it sees a TITLE line, it concatenates the line with the saved number, and then replaces the first sequence of digits it finds with the saved value that comes at the end (and tosses that appended data away.)

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -f
/^###MSMS:/{
p
s/[^0-9]//g
h
d
}
/^TITLE=/{
G
s/\([^0-9]*\)[0-9]*\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\1\3\2/
}
```

Running this script on the provided sample data yields:

```
###MS: 12/
###MSMS: 13/
BEGIN IONS
TITLE= Cmpd 13, +MSn(507.7145), 0.1 min
PEPMASS=507.71453  5708

###MS: 12/
###MSMS: 14/
BEGIN IONS
TITLE= Cmpd 14, +MSn(637.6461), 0.1 min
PEPMASS=637.64610  8328
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested,

I dropped the regex approach and wrote a Python script instead, solving the situation. (MGF is the name of the file)

```
# Read the MGF lines
mgfLines = mgf.readlines ()
# Create the final list of lines
outputLines = []
# Scroll the lines
for lines in mgfLines:
    # If there is no ##MSMS value or TITLE
    if ("###MSMS" not in lines and "TITLE" not in lines):
        # Write the line to the output file
        outputLines.append (lines)
    # If there is the ##MSMS value
    if "###MSMS" in lines:
        # Write the line to the output file
        outputLines.append (lines)
        #### Store the value of the MSMS
        # Index the space and the /, and in between there is the MSMS number
        for i in range(len(lines)):
            if (lines[i] == " "):
                spaceIndex = i
        for i in range(len(lines)):
            if (lines[i] == "/"):
                slashIndex = i
        # The MSMS number is in between
        msmsValueFinal = int (lines[spaceIndex+1 : slashIndex])
    # If there is the TITLE value (the MSMS value has to be passed to TITLE)
    if "TITLE" in lines:
        # Split the line at the commas
        titleLineSplitted = str.split (lines, ",")
        # Three pieces are generated: the last two will be joined back together with a comma, the first will have the TITLE Cmpd number replaced by the MSMS value
        titleLineSplitted[0] = "TITLE= Cmpd " + str(msmsValueFinal)
        # Join back the pieces
        finalTitleLine = titleLineSplitted[0] + "," + titleLineSplitted[1] + "," + titleLineSplitted[2]
        # Write the final line to the file
        outputLines.append (finalTitleLine)
```